# Find which subpattern matched in regex

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible via regex find which sub pattern match in string, suppose we want check that
"2D3" via "\d{1,}D{1,}".

```
string pattern  = "\d{1,}D\d{1,}";
string str = "2D3";
var r = new Regex(pattern)
if(r.IsMatch(str))
{
   Dictionary<string, string> Out = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   //Some Code Here???
   Log(Out);
}

/////////////Out Must Be/////////
({"\d{1,}", "2"},
{"D", "D"},
{"\d{1,}", "3"})
////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Seems you are trying to get the matching value for each group, work with capturing group? `(\d{1,})(D)(\d{1,})`

Comment: you made a typo in your reges (It should probably be: `\d{1,}D\d{1,}` , that last `\d` is missing)

Comment: What makes a sub pattern? If your dynamic input (as per the comment on @YongShun's answer) clearly delineates the sub patterns then you can build the regex by enclosing each in capturing brackets and then concatenate them. E.g. `string[] subPatterns = ...; string re = "("+string.join(")(", subPatterns) + ")";`. Use element of `subPatterns` for the dictionary keys and captured groups for the values. (Not ans answer because there are too many unknowns in the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you are trying to get the value for each group, thus you need the **capturing group** `()` in your regex pattern.

```
(\d{1,})(D)(\d{1,})
```

And provide the index to get the value of each group.

```cs
string pattern  = @"(\d{1,})(D)(\d{1,})";
string str = "2D3";
var r = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = r.Match(str);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1st capturing group: {0}", match.Groups[1]); 
    Console.WriteLine("2nd capturing group: {0}", match.Groups[2]); 
    Console.WriteLine("3rd capturing group: {0}", match.Groups[3]); 
}
```

---

I don't think without capturing group(s), you are able to capture each value by portion according to the regex (portion). If you allow the user to input the regex by portion/group as mentioned by @AdrianHHH, then you can manipulate the regex pattern by adding the `(` and `)` in the front and end respectively.

And since you want to capture each regex pattern and its respective matching value, storing both values in a `Dictionary` is not a good choice, as `Dictionary` is not allowed to store the same key.

```cs
List<dynamic> Out = new List<dynamic>();
List<string> patternGroups = new List<string> { @"\d{1,}", "D", @"\d{1,}" };

string pattern  = String.Join("", patternGroups.Select(x => $"({x})"));
string str = "2D3";
var r = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = r.Match(str);

if (match.Success)
{           
    for (int i = 0; i < patternGroups.Count; i++)
    {
        Out.Add(new 
                { 
                    Regex = patternGroups[i], 
                    Value = match.Groups[i + 1].Value 
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oh10ku)

Comment: The value `D` is constant and I think it mustn't into a capturing group.

Comment: Additionally use named groups: `(?<first>\d{1,})(D)(?<second>\d{1,})`

Comment: Side note: we can use `+` instead of `{1,}`: `(\d+)D(\d+)`, we don't want group for `D` since it's a static text

Comment: the pattern is dynamic and i dont want force user to group it. and another thing is that if i force user to enter regex as a group , how can get first part of dictionary keys, use another regex?

Comment: Hi, hmmm, would say that this could be complex (doubt that the regex pattern without group is able to achieve) Unless as what @AdrianHHH mentioned in the comment, you are allowed to let the user key in the regex part by part, then you can control the final regex pattern by appending each regex part with capturing group.

Comment: *if i force user to enter regex as a group , how can get first part of dictionary keys*, well, if you allow the user to enter regex as group, you can iterate with `match.Groups` and add the regex and value into dictionary. And I doubt that let say you have regex group which have the same pattern, dictionary not allow to insert with same key.

Comment: [Demo 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oh10ku)

Comment: Just a small suggestion for readability: `{1,}` can be replaced with `+`.